# Expressing Numbers Without Any Decimal Presumptions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems, paradoxes, arithmetic-functions, multisets

I have long been uncomfortable with how numbers in alternative bases are expressed.  Alternative bases are marketed as transcending our arbitrary base-$10$ conventions, but I wonder if they really succeed.

If we write the expression $31_5$, the $31$ is in base-$5$, while the $5$ is presumably in base-$10$, an unfortunate asymmetry.  If history had unfolded differently, the base itself would be written in a different base.  Likewise for that base, and so on recursively.  The cardinality of the multiset $\{m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m\}$ is $17_{(10_{(10_{(10_{(10_{(10_{(10_{(10_{...})})})})})})})}$.  It is possible to just reference the cardinality of the multiset directly to avoid this infinite recursion, or to truncate the chain at any point, i.e., $17_{(10_{(10_{card\{m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a\}})})}$.

To capture the advantages of positional notation, the same quantity could be represented as $$card\{m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a,\ t\}card\{m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a\}^{card\{\}} + card\{m\}card\{m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a,\ t,\ h,\ m,\ a\}^{card\{m\}}$$

> Decimal users can read this as $7 * 10^0 + 1 * 10^1$ but without the recursion problem implicit in each of these digits.

Another representation would be $$card\{m,\ a\}card\{m,\ a,\ t\}^{card\{\}} + card\{m,\ a\}card\{m,\ a,\ t\}^{card\{m\}} + card\{m\}card\{m,\ a,\ t\}^{card\{m,\ a\}}$$

> This is secretly ternary; $2 * 3^0 + 2 * 3^1 + 1 * 3^2$.

How can I convert a representation purely in terms of cardinalities like these into a natural number of the form $n_b$, in such a manner that the base of $n$, the base of $b$, the base of the base of $b$, and so on recursively, are written in a shared base other than decimal, as if history had truly unfolded differently, and there wasn't any decimal presumption to fall back on under the hood?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151320/discussion-on-question-by-user10478-expressing-numbers-without-any-decimal-presu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is write the base subscript in **tick notation** (often called "unary," even though that's a clear abuse of terminology): e.g. $$17_{''''''''}$$ is uniquely interpretable as (in our base-ten notation) $1\cdot 8+7\cdot 1$. What base the reader is taking as default will not affect their ability to count the number of ticks indicating the *intended* base.

Of course this quickly becomes unreadable. We can make things nicer by mixing in arithmetic operations, e.g. $$17_{('')\cdot (('')+(''))}.$$ And in the other direction, if we're worried about what arithmetic operations are taken as basic ("what if we're communicating with aliens who don't know what multiplication is?"), then we can express **everything** in this tick notation. Ultimately, every "basic" arithmetical operation can be built up from successor (which is basically what tick notation is) and *(primitive) recursion*.

Comment: I believe this is the same thing I did using the cardinality of a multiset to truncate the infinite chain of bases.  You are just using the cardinality of a multiset of ticks instead the symbols m, a, t, and h.  This is great for reducing ambiguity in understanding the question, but ultimately the base of the number and the base of the base are still asymmetric.

Comment: $17_{\text{eight}}^{\,}$ or  $30_{\text{five}}^{\,}$ can be seen an alternative, though some people might prefer to write these as $17_{\text{八}}^{\,}$ or $30_{\text{πεντε}}^{\,}$ or something else of similar form